# Recursion problem, function takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

I am using recursion to traverse a tree using binary instruction: 0 to go left and 1 to go right.

Never the less when I want to recurse to find the next leaf I can't because of a function argument problem (I don't understand it actually).

I have tried to use a helper function but, couldn't accurately write it

```
def decode(root, encode, original_root):
    if len(encode)== 0:
        return ""
    if encode[0] == "0":

        if root.left() != None:
            print("left", root.getValue())
            encode.pop(0)
            decode(root.left(), encode, original_root)
        else:
            print('last', root.getValue())
            return root.getValue() + decode(original_root, encode, original_root)

    if encode[0]== '1':
        if root.right()!= None:
            print('right',root.getValue())
            encode.pop(0)
            decode(root.right(), root.right(), encode, original_root)
        else:
            print(root.getValue())
            return root.getValue() + decode(original_root, encode, original_root)
```

Comment: `decode(root.right(), root.right(), encode, original_root)`-- count the arguments

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this line you pass 4 arguments to decode function. It probably should get only 3 arguments:
`decode(root.right(), root.right(), encode, original_root)`

Did you mean to write:
`decode(root.right(), encode, original_root)`
?

Comment: Can you update your answer with a suggestion of what the correct parameters should be?